# How do I explain that software implemented model selection procedures should not be used unsupervised?

Tags: regression, model-selection, aic, bias, unbiased-estimator

I know that people generally say that procedures which select a model based on information criterion lead to inconsistent model selections.

I read a paper by Leeb and Potscher (2005), MODEL SELECTION AND INFERENCE: FACTS AND FICTION which supports this theory.

Regardless of the kind of information criterion we use (a consistent one like BIC or a conservative criterion like  AIC) we will sometimes get seriously biased variables.

As there is no way to actually check if our model is biased in this way, since the examples provided by Leeb and Potscher depend on their sample design (even the design is a very general one), we could be very dull and use the model selection procedure nevertheless.

Another more common issue is that an omitted variable biases the coefficients as well, if a regressor is correlated with the error term.

So I would say that one should always check the changes in coefficients estimated if a regressor gets kicked out. Even if the relationship between an omitted regressor and the dependent variable is very low (which is the reason why it got kicked out) it would still be a viable source of bias. So one must not only check the usual significance criterion, but also check the changes in coefficients, to minimize the risk of biased coefficients?

Comment: Explain to who? I think the basic rule for model selection is to put it in context: that's why automated model selection is no good. You always have to check what you are doing and not perform model selection criterions (AIC/BIC) blindly. My motto is that 'these serve as a support for you, not as a kickstart'.

I would also add that bias is not the only thing to worry about; what about the variance? What are you aiming for? Prediction?

Comment: Can you explain why the checks that you advocate cannot be similarly automated?  In my experience manual model selection often provides worse predictive performance than automated schemes (see for example the results of machine learning challenges, where those at the top of the leader board generally finish quite a way down the final rankings because they have been manually over-fitting the model).

Comment: @Néstor In some courses in university model selection is thought as a necessary step to finish the hole procedure of finding a adequate model. I agree with you that the context is important too since sometimes a non significant regressor is of interest as well. What do you mean with variance? My aim is to tell a college of mine my automated model selection should not be done. A example I can come up with is a design I've been working on. The regressor of interest would be a dummy which is non significant. In order to check it's influence we need to keep this regressor.